# Nested Group by LINQ to Nested object

Tags: c#, performance, linq, refactoring

I am unable to solve this problem with the LINQ Query.

So we have the table structure of Book as follows:

```
LibraryId || LibraryName || ShelveId || ShelveName || Cost || Name || ForeName || Stuff
```

I want to group by Library first, then by Shelve of Book. A Library is a list of Shelve and a Shelve is a list of book. Performance matters. This is a fragment of real data.

```
var table = new[] {
    new Book (1, "Green", 42, "A", 10, "Gra", "Bar", "etc."),
    new Book (1, "Green", 43, "B", 21, "Grb", "Bar", "etc."),
    new Book (2, "Blue", 652, "C", 10, "Blc", "Bar", "etc."),
    new Book (2, "Blue", 652, "C", 01, "Bl2", "Bar", "etc."),
    new Book (2, "Blue", 123, "D", 12, "Bld", "Bar", "etc."),
    new Book (8, "White", 94, "E", 14, "Foo", "Bar", "etc."),
    new Book (9, "Grey", 142, "F", 11, "Foo", "Bar", "etc."),
    new Book (9, "Grey", 142, "F", 12, "Bar", "Bar", "etc.")
};
```

Class:

```
class Book
{
    public int LibraryId {get;set;}
    public string LibraryName {get;set;}

    public int ShelveId {get;set;}
    public string ShelveName {get;set;}

    public int Cost {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string ForeName {get;set;}
    public string Stuff {get;set;}

    public Book(int libraryId, string libraryName, int shelveId, string shelveName
                , int cost, string name, string foreName, string stuff)
    {
        LibraryId = libraryId;
        LibraryName = libraryName;
        ShelveId = shelveId;
        ShelveName = shelveName;
        Cost = cost;
        Name = name;
        ForeName = foreName;
        Stuff = stuff;
    }
}

class Library
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int Cost {get;set;}
    public List<Shelve> Shelves {get;set;}

    public Library (Shelve shelve)
    {
        Id = shelve.Books[0].LibraryId;
        Name = shelve.Books[0].LibraryName;
        Cost = shelve.Cost;
        Shelves = new List<Shelve> {shelve};
    }
}

class Shelve
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int Cost {get;set;}
    public List<Book> Books {get;set;}

    public Shelve (Book book)
    {
        Id = book.ShelveId;
        Name = book.ShelveName;
        Cost = book.Cost;
        Books = new List<Book> {book};
    }
}
```

I achieve my behavior with a good old `foreach`:

```
var libraries = new List<Library> { new Library (new Shelve(table[0])) };
foreach (var item in table.Skip(1))
{
    if (item.LibraryId != libraries.Last().Id)
    {
        libraries.Add(new Library(new Shelve(item)));
        continue;
    }

    if (item.ShelveId != libraries.Last().Shelves.Last().Id)
    {
        libraries.Last().Cost += item.Cost;
        libraries.Last().Shelves.Add(new Shelve(item));
        continue;
    }

    libraries.Last().Cost += item.Cost;
    libraries.Last().Shelves.Last().Cost += item.Cost;
    libraries.Last().Shelves.Last().Books.Add(item);
}
var total = libraries.Sum(x => x.Cost);
```

As far as I know, this is a O(n) solution.

Now, I would like to refactor it. I think we can do something with `GroupBy`. I tried this:

```
var grouped = table
    .GroupBy(l => new { l.ShelveId, l.LibraryId})
    .GroupBy(l => l.Key.LibraryId);

foreach(var country in grouped)
{
    foreach(var state in country)
    {
        foreach(var personInState in state)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(personInState.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

But I don't know how to Sum the cost and add LibraryName and ShelveName into each `Library` and `Shelve`.

[Try it Online!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IyWsNY) (with basic tests)

Comment: Could you please edit your question and paste the class definitions of Library, Shelve, and Book?

Comment: @RuiJarimba Done.

Comment: `Library` and `Shelf` (not `Shelve`, which is a verb) really shouldn't contain the `Cost` property: If we see them as tables in a database, this breaks the normalization rules. If your'e willing to ommit it, you can use a nested query (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/create-a-nested-group)).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can simplify it by using calculated properties as below

```
class Shelve
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public List<Book> Books {get;set;} = List<Book>();
    public int Cost 
    {
        get{ return this.Books.Sum(x => x.Cost); } 
    }
}
```

and you can do the same with the `Library` class...

```
class Library
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public List<Shelve> Shelves {get;set;} = new List<Shelve>();
    public int Cost 
    {
        get{ return this.Shelves.Sum(x => x.Cost); } 
    }
}
```

I think it'd add clarity to your business logic code and you won't need to bang your head with complex group by expressions

Comment: Indeed it is working. But  arent we calling the sum a lot of time? When I do `Library.Cost`, I am going to walk every Shelve calling their `Cost` which trigger another `Sum` waling every `Cost` of each Book, don't I?

Comment: @aloisdg I actually missed the "performance matters" part of your question. Apologies for that. I haven't run any performance profiling at all on this approach...so, I can't answer that part of the question. I'll leave the answer just in case it helps someone else

Comment: Yes sure. It is a clean answer neverttheless :)